# Failing to start my spring boot application due to 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am a beginner in spring boot and am trying to write a simple spring boot application. 
My folder structure is as follows:

```
  -> Project

       -> build.gradle

       -> settings.gradle

       -> src/main/java

           -> package

               -> Main.java

               -> UserController.java

               -> UserRespository.java

           -> dto

               -> User.java

       ->src/main/resouces

               -> application.properties
```

My build.gradle is as follows :

```
    buildscript {
            repositories {
                          jcenter()
                         }
    dependencies {
           classpath(
                  'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle- plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE'

                     )
          classpath('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34')
                 }
           }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
              mavenCentral()
                 }

   dependencies {
         compile(
              'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator',
              'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web',
              'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'       
                )
        compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
        testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
               }
```

The application.properties is as follows:

```
   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user
   spring.datasource.username=root
   spring.datasource.password=root
   spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect  
   spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
   spring.jpa.show-sql = true
```

My Main.java is as follows:-

```
  import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
  import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
  import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
  import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

  @SpringBootApplication
  @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
   public class Main {

           public static void main(String[] args) {
                   SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
      };

  }
```

I am able to successfully build the application. If I run the application , I get Unable to start application with the following stacktrace:

```
     2017-08-14 20:43:02.976  WARN 27205 --- [           main]  ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context  initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
   2017-08-14 20:43:02.978  INFO 27205 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
   2017-08-14 20:43:03.007  INFO 27205 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

   Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration   report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
   2017-08-14 20:43:03.198 ERROR 27205 --- [           main]         o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

    ***************************
     APPLICATION FAILED TO START
    ***************************

    Description:

    Parameter 0 of constructor in  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'javax.sql.Data Source' that could not be found.
         - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'
         - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.jta.XADataSourceWrapper; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans


     Action:

       Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' in your configuration.
```

I have checked the dependencies tree and can find both hibernate as well as mysql connector in it. 
Have tried removing @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class}) , in that case I get Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: why you exclude DataSourceAutoConfiguration?

Comment: I was going through all the existing answers and we're trying out . Have removed the exclusion but getting cannot load driver for mysql

Comment: i think problem is in driver dependency .can u share code in github?

Comment: Remove `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` from you properties. Clean and rebuild your project. Spring Boot will create the correct datasource from the JDBC url.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `dto` package inside into your `Main.java` class package, In your case it should be like `src/main/java/package/dto`

So when spring-boot scans, your entity will be visible to the scanner.

Make sure you have added the MySQL driver dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```